# ReactJs child didn't update after parent state changed

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to build a dynamic component using ReactJS. So, I have a products list and each time the user would like to add a new product, he will click on the + button. this will create a new product and add it to the list. the list had a button named delete all to delete all products.

To delete all products, i used a state in the products list initialized with "created" on the component creation and when the user clicks on delete all i'm changing it to "deleted" toupdate the childs (products) using ComponentWillUpdate callback.

here is some code :

index.js

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Dynamic List</h1>
        <ProductList />
        <hr />
        <h1>Static List</h1>
        <ProductListStatic />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Product.js

```
class Product extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      state: "created"
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (
      this.props.parentState === "deleted" &&
      this.state.state === "created"
    ) {
      this.setState({ state: "deleted" });
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.state !== "deleted") {
      return (
        <div style={{ margin: "5px" }}>
          Product.....
          <button onClick={this.props.addNewProduct}>+</button>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

my ProductList.js

```
class ProductList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [],
      state: "created"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let newProducts = [...this.state.products];
    newProducts.push(
      <Product
        key={0}
        addNewProduct={this.addNewProduct}
        parentState={this.state.state}
      />
    );
    this.setState({ products: newProducts });
  }

  addNewProduct = () => {
    let length = this.state.products.length;
    const newProducts = [
      ...this.state.products,
      <Product
        key={length}
        addNewProduct={this.addNewProduct}
        parentState={this.state.state}
      />
    ];
    this.setState({ products: newProducts });
  };

  deleteAll = () => {
    this.setState({ state: "deleted" });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.products}
        <button style={{ marginTop: "20px" }} onClick={this.deleteAll}>
          Delete All
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Well this doesn't update the childs and i don't know why. i think that's because the list is dynamic. I gived it a try using a static list and it works fine (code below).

ProductListStatic.js

```
class ProductListStatic extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [],
      state: "created"
    };
  }

  deleteAll = () => {
    console.log("delete all");
    this.setState({ state: "deleted" });
  };

  render() {
    let products = [
      <Product
        key={0}
        addNewProduct={this.addNewProduct}
        parentState={this.state.state}
      />,
      <Product
        key={1}
        addNewProduct={this.addNewProduct}
        parentState={this.state.state}
      />
    ];
    return (
      <div>
        {products}
        <button style={{ marginTop: "20px" }} onClick={this.deleteAll}>
          Delete All
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

here is a demo : [SandBox live dome](https://codesandbox.io/embed/hungry-dew-0eqfj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

anynoe knows why it doesn't work with dynamic products ?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code in your question? The sandbox might change or go down over time, rendering the question useless for future visitors.

Comment: you need to remove the products too, setting a state alone wont really work   
    this.setState({ 
      state: "deleted",
       products:[] 
    });

Comment: one thing, on the code sandbox, you are intermixing UI state management (which should be focused purely on data types (like Objects, Numbers, Booleans, etc.) with rendering JSX. Don't put JSX in UI state. UI state should contain only serializable data types, for a multitude of reasons, including how React works. So in your render function, map over the state to then return JSX, and anywhere you call setState, make sure its data type is native to JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that JSX elements in a state array have no idea that they need to be re-rendered when the parent re-renders. In the static version, the children are created directly in the JSX, so behavior for re-renders is normal. Storing the *data* for the children in the state array then creating them by calling `.map` on that state array per render is a reasonable solution.

Beyond this, the overall design seems needlessly complex. I don't think child `Product`s should be concerned about when they render or if a product should be added in the parent with a callback from the child. It's much simpler to keep all of this information in the parent. The rendering can be implict--if we want a new item, push it onto the product/items array and if we want to clear all items, set the array to `[]`. No need for `this.state.state`.

Here's a proof-of-concept:

```js
const mockProduct = () => ({
  name: [
    "apple", "banana", "cherry", "kiwi",
    "watermelon", "pineapple", "blueberry"
  ][~~(Math.random()*7)],
  price: ~~(Math.random() * 5) + 0.99
});

const Product = props => 
  <div>
    <span>{props.name}</span>
    <span>{props.price}</span>
  </div>
;

class Products extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {products: [mockProduct()]};
    this.addNewProduct = this.addNewProduct.bind(this);
    this.deleteAll = this.deleteAll.bind(this);
  }
  
  addNewProduct() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      products: state.products.concat(mockProduct())
    }));
  }
  
  deleteAll() {
    this.setState({products: []});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          {this.state.products.map((e, i) =>
            <div 
              style={{display: "flex"}} 
              key={`${i}-${e.name}`} 
            >
              <Product name={e.name} price={e.price} />
              <button onClick={this.addNewProduct}>+</button>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.deleteAll}>delete all</button>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Products />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

A container for rows might be in order if you plan to add additional buttons and data for each product. Then, callbacks would become necessary for rows to signal to parents when an change should be applied to an item. This is dependent on your design goals and is premature at this point (after removing rendering concerns from `Product`, there isn't much left to justify its existence).

Comment: thnx ggorien for the poc. like you said there is no need of childs state if we want to delete them all. but, i'd like to add a state for these childs (the name of the product and its price) and a new button to the list 'send all'. when user clicks on it. it triggers a sendToServer function on each child to save the product. i don't know how to change my design to use yours in such a case ?

Comment: I'd still put the "send all" button in the parent, so I think this example is still relevant for that design. It'd be the same as "delete all" except instead of (or in addition to) clearing the list, you call an async function that invokes `axios.post` or `fetch` etc using the data from the `products` array. This is another benefit from keeping raw data instead o JSX in the array is it's pretty much ready to be posted.

Comment: I did like you said and it's working fine now. thnx a lot for your help.